# Error creating bean with name 'weatherController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'weatherService';

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-boot, model-view-controller

I'm trying to develop basic Spring Boot REST API CRUD with Spring Data H2

Error is:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'weatherController': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field 'weatherService'; nested exception
>   is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'weatherService': Unsatisfied dependency
>   expressed through field 'weatherRepository'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'weatherRepository': Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed
>   to create query for method public abstract java.util.List
>   com.example.springboot2.WeatherRepository.findByNameContaining(java.lang.String)!
>   No property name found for type Weather!

I have finished my code but it's not working and I can't find any solution, any help will be appriciated

Weather.java

```
    package com.example.springboot2;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import java.time.LocalDate;

@Entity
public class Weather {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)// Otomatik oluşturulmasın
    private long id;
    private String city;
    private LocalDate dateMeasured;
    private double tempMin;
    private double tempMax;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public LocalDate getDateMeasured() {
        return dateMeasured;
    }

    public void setDateMeasured(LocalDate dateMeasured) {
        this.dateMeasured = dateMeasured;
    }

    public double getTempMin() {
        return tempMin;
    }

    public void setTempMin(double tempMin) {
        this.tempMin = tempMin;
    }

    public double getTempMax() {
        return tempMax;
    }

    public void setTempMax(double tempMax) {
        this.tempMax = tempMax;
    }
}
```

WeatherController.java

```
package com.example.springboot2;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/weather")
public class WeatherController{


    @Autowired
    private WeatherService weatherService;

    @GetMapping()
    public ResponseEntity<List<Weather>> getAllWeathers() {
        List<Weather> weatherList = weatherService.getAllWeathers();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(weatherList, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Weather> getWeatherById(
            @PathVariable("id") final Long id) {
        Weather weather = weatherService.getWeatherById(id);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(weather, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @PostMapping()
    public ResponseEntity<Weather> saveWeather(
            @RequestBody final  Weather weather) {
        Weather savedWeather = weatherService.saveWeather(weather);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(savedWeather, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @PutMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Weather> updateWeatherById(
            @PathVariable("id") final Long id,
            @RequestBody final Weather weatherToUpdate) {
        Weather updatedWeather
                = weatherService.updateWeatherById(id, weatherToUpdate);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(updatedWeather, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<String> deleteWeatherById(
            @PathVariable("id") final Long id) {
        weatherService.deleteWeatherById(id);
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Success", HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping("/search1/{searchString}")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Weather>> getWeatherByNameContaining(
            @PathVariable("searchString") final String searchString) {
        List<Weather> weatherList
                = weatherService.getWeatherByNameContaining(searchString);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(weatherList, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping("/search2/{searchString}")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Weather>> getWeatherByNameLike(
            @PathVariable("searchString") final String searchString) {
        List<Weather> weatherList
                = weatherService.getWeatherByNameLike(searchString);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(weatherList, HttpStatus.OK);
    }





}
```

WeatherRepository

```
package com.example.springboot2;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.List;

public interface WeatherRepository extends CrudRepository<Weather,Long> {


    List<Weather> findByNameContaining(String value);
    @Query("SELECT w FROM Weather w WHERE w.city LIKE %:value%")
    List<Weather> findByNameLike(@Param("value") String value);

}
```

WeatherService

```
package com.example.springboot2;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;
@Service("weatherService")
public interface WeatherService {

    List<Weather> getAllWeathers();
    Weather getWeatherById(Long id);
    Weather saveWeather(Weather weather);
    Weather updateWeatherById(Long id, Weather weatherToUpdate);
    void deleteWeatherById(Long id);
    List<Weather> getWeatherByNameContaining(String searchString);
    List<Weather> getWeatherByNameLike(String searchString);


}
```

WeatherServiceImpl

```
package com.example.springboot2;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;
@Component
@Service("weatherService")
public class WeatherServiceImpl implements WeatherService {

    @Autowired
    private WeatherRepository weatherRepository;

    @Override
    public List<Weather> getAllWeathers() {
        return (List<Weather>) weatherRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Weather getWeatherById(final Long id) {
        return weatherRepository.findById(id).get();
    }

    @Override
    public Weather saveWeather(final Weather weather) {
        return weatherRepository.save(weather);
    }

    @Override
    public Weather updateWeatherById(
            final Long id, final Weather weatherToUpdate) {
        Weather weatherFromDb = weatherRepository.findById(id).get();
        weatherFromDb.setCity(weatherToUpdate.getCity());
        weatherFromDb.setDateMeasured(weatherToUpdate.getDateMeasured());
        weatherFromDb.setTempMax(weatherToUpdate.getTempMax());
        weatherFromDb.setTempMin(weatherToUpdate.getTempMin());
        return weatherRepository.save(weatherFromDb);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteWeatherById(final Long id) {
        weatherRepository.deleteById(id);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Weather> getWeatherByNameContaining(final String searchString) {
        return weatherRepository.findByNameContaining(searchString);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Weather> getWeatherByNameLike(final String searchString) {
        return weatherRepository.findByNameLike(searchString);
    }
}
```

Springboot2Application

```
package com.example.springboot2;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.example")

public class Springboot2Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Springboot2Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>springboot2</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>springboot2</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Please help me to solve the error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `WeatherRepository` you have:

```
List<Weather> findByNameContaining(String value);
```

Now, this is a derived query method (more [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-derived-queries)).

The problem is your `Weather` entity does not have a property named `name` which you are using in your method.

The method should be:

```
List<Weather> findByCityContaining(String value);
```

Answer (score 4):

`Weather` is not having property `name` so you can't use `findByNameContaining` method in repository.

Answer (score 2):

This line gives you the information about your error

```
BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'weatherRepository'
```

Your `WeatherRepository` bean is not being created. Make sure you annotate your `WeatherRepository` class. Typically this will be with `@Repository`. See the [spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/package-summary.html) for a list of stereotypes.

Generally you can use component/service/repository interchangeably with no adverse affects (i.e. it doesn't matter which one you use) however it's recommended you use the one that is appropriate for your purposes.

Also note that your `WeatherService` interface does NOT require an annotation as you are not instantiating a bean.

`WeatherServiceImpl` requires only one of either `@Component` or `@Service` and not both. (suggest `@Service`). You also do not need the name qualifier as you are not accessing the service by name, or trying to have multiple WeatherService beans. i.e. you can just annotate with `@Service` instead of `@Service("weatherService")`

Comment: Thank you for such information I updated the project with your right information